# Can using cat create problems when passing the output to other commands?

Tags: bash

In bash, there are multiple ways to direct input and output. For example, these commands do the same thing:

```
sort <input_file >output_file
cat input_file | sort >output_file
```

Generally I'd prefer the second way, because I prefer my commands to read left-to-right.

But the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4714043/what-is-the-best-way-to-sort-30gb-of-strings-with-a-computer-with-4gb-of-ram-usin) says:

> "sort" can use temporary files to work with input files larger than memory

Which makes me wonder, when sorting a huge file, if `cat` would short-circuit that process.

Can using `cat` create problems when passing the output to other commands?

Comment: Update: although my question is about potential performance issues, I'm just asking so I can be aware of the possibilities. In the vast majority of cases, it will be better to optimize for programmer time (which is expensive) by writing a command that's as easy as possible to read and debug, rather than optimizing for processor time (which is cheap).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a term I throw around a lot called [**Useless Use of Cat** (UUoC)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_(Unix)#Useless_use_of_cat) and the 2nd option is exactly that.  When a utility can take input on STDIN (such as `sort`) using redirection not only saves you an extra call to an external process such as `cat` but it also prevents the overhead of a pipeline.

Other than the extra process and pipeline, the only other "problem" that I see would be you would be subject to the pipeline buffering.

#### Update

Apparently, there is even a website dedicated to giving out a [UUoC Award](http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html)

Comment: I like their suggestion of `less` to quickly view a file.

Answer (score 2):

"I prefer my commands to read left-to-right"

```
<input_file sort >output_file
```

(The canonical way to write this is of course `sort input_file >output_file`.)

Comment: +1: I wondered whether to note that.  It works, of course, for a single input file.

Comment: Fair enough. Although for the arrows example, I know that when I first saw something like this (I was new to the command line), I wondered why the arrows didn't point where the things were going. Like `input_file> sort >output_file`. But that's just a matter of learning the conventions.

Comment: Yeah, I suppose the convention is _command_ _input_files_ `>` _output_

Answer (score 2):

The 'sort' command handles large files regardless of whether the input arrives via standard input and a pipe or I/O redirection or by being directly named on the command line.

Note that you could (and probably should) write:

```
sort -o output_file input_file
```

That will work correctly even if the input and output files are the same (or if you have multiple input files, one of which is also the output file).

I see that SiegeX has already take you to task for abusing cat -- feline abuse as it is also known. I'll support his efforts.  There are times when it is appropriate to use `cat`.  There are fewer times when it is appropriate than is often recognized.

One example of appropriate use is with the `tr` command and multiple sources of data:

```
cat "$@" | tr ...
```

That is necessary because `tr` only reads its standard input and only writes to its standard output - the ultimate in 'pure filter' programs.

The authors of Unix have also noted that the general purpose 'cat inputs | command' construct is used instead of the more specialized input redirection (citation missing - books needed not at hand).

Comment: I guess the question is: will `cat` stream the file contents to `sort`, just as though `sort` were reading it from disk? Or does `cat` have to load the whole thing into memory before handing it to `sort`?

Comment: @Nathan: typically, `cat` will read the file in chunks (possibly quite big ones) before writing chunks to its own standard output.  It is unlikely that `cat` would read the whole file into memory before copying the data to the output; it might do something analogous if it memory-mapped the file, perhaps, but in general, it could be reading from many different sources (files, pipes, FIFOs, sockets). If you follow @SiegeX's link, you'll see that when the output from `cat` is piped to `sort`, the behaviour is almost the same as if `sort` read the file directly; almost but not quite identical.